# Issues mirroring and SVN repository

Tags: svn, svnsync

I am trying to mirror a repository to my local machine. From what I have read the best way to approach this is using svnsync. When I go to set up this i am getting errors back that svnadmin and svnsync are unknown commands. Is there an add on I need to download to be able to perform these commands? The basic command line commands for svn are working fine such as checkout, update, etc

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your svn?  [With the new version of subversion 1.4 you have a new tool called svnsync with which you can maintain mirror repositories quite easily](http://blog.notreally.org/2006/11/30/setting-up-a-subversion-mirror-repository-using-svnsync/).

Comment: The version is 1.5.1 but it doesnt seem to recognise the svnsync command

Comment: It's not a command, actually, it's independent tool. So, just try typing in command console directly:

> svnsync

Comment: Have tried this also but doesnt seem to work. getting error " svnsync is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Is there a seperate link I need to add to the path for this?

Comment: What's your OS? It could be that under Linux you have bare svn? Under Windows I'm using SilkSvn which is actually a package of tools (i.e. in Program Files\SilkSvn\bin I have tools: svnadmin, svnsync, svnlook, etc along with svn itself.

Comment: Using windows xp, Collabnet Subversion Client installed. There seems to be no bin in its install folder just dll files